Как сделать отправку бесшумных сообщений через бот тг?
Сделал парсер, но никак не могу разобраться как сделать так, чтобы бот отправлял сообщения бесшумно:
if message_id in message_storage:
    stored_message = message_storage[message_id]

    # Извлечение ID канала из текста сообщения с клавиатуры модерации
    match = re.search(r'ID (-?\d+)', callback_query.message.text)
    if match:
        destination_channel_id = int(match.group(1))
    else:
        # Обработка ошибки: ID канала не найден
        await bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query.id, "Ошибка: ID канала не найден.")
        return

    if isinstance(stored_message, list):  # Обработка альбома
        first_message_caption = stored_message[0].text
        media_group = [message.media for message in stored_message]
        await client.send_file(destination_channel_id, media_group, caption=first_message_caption)

        # Удаление сообщений из технического канала
        message_ids = [msg.id for msg in stored_message]
        await client.delete_messages(technical_channel_id, message_ids)
    else:  # Обработка одиночного сообщения
        # Отправка сообщения на канал с извлеченным ID
        await client.send_message(destination_channel_id, stored_message.text, file=stored_message.media)

        # Удаление сообщения из технического канала
        await client.delete_messages(technical_channel_id, message_id)

Chat gpt подсказывает добавить в     параметр disable_notification=True, но это не работает, какие еще способы могут быть? На просторах интернета решения не нашел.
Отправка сообщения на канал с извлеченным ID
        await client.send_message(destination_channel_id, stored_message.text, file=stored_message.media, disable_notification=True)


Или я чего-то не понимаю или... уведомления же включает сам пользователь. https://i.imgur.com/a9znQDH.jpeg

Это оно и есть. У sendMessage есть параметр disable_notification: Bool
